# What NSRange return value do you check for when you call selectedRange on a UITextView that is not currently being edited?

Tags: ios, uitextview

What NSRange return value do you check for when you call selectedRange on a UITextView that is not currently being edited?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
NSRange range = textView.selectedRange;

if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
  //The textfield was not selected.

} else {
  //There is a valid range.

}
```